# R codes for Bayesian Credible Intervals and p-values for a Additive Bayesian Network model

Tags: r, machine-learning, bayesian, modeling, markov-process

I am using Additive Bayesian Network (ABN) to model the relationship between cereal crop production and climate variables and want to generate credible intervals and p-values for my model coefficients.

My challenge is which appropriate **r code** will help me get my outputs. I am using RStudio.

Thank you.